# Remove element byattribute from Json array using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I need to remove the attribute name 'version_Dev' and 'version_Value' from the JSON Array.

```
var jsonObject_Value = [
Object { name="TitleDAY",  value=undefined}, 
Object { name="Name",  value=Jessica}, 
Object { name="Code",  value="rt123"}, 
Object { name="ForId",  value="26"}, 
Object { name="TypeId",  value="262"}, 
Object { name="Title",  value=null}, 
Object { name="version_Value",  value=1}, 
Object { name="Id",  value=140767}, 
Object { name="version_Dev",  value=1}, 
Object { name="haz",  value=null},]
```

If i tried with delete jsonObject, if serialization happen in json object or any new field is get added the bellow solution is No use it will delete some other attribute.:

```
delete jsonObject_Value[7];
delete jsonObject_Value[9];
```

Expected Output:

```
[
Object { name="TitleDAY",  value=undefined}, 
Object { name="Name",  value=Jessica}, 
Object { name="Code",  value="rt123"}, 
Object { name="ForId",  value="26"}, 
Object { name="TypeId",  value="262"}, 
Object { name="Title",  value=null}, 
undefined, 
Object { name="Id",  value=140767}, 
undefined, 
Object { name="haz",  value=null}, 
]
```

Comment: Firstly, nothing about this has *anything* to do with JSON. What you have is an array of objects. Secondly, it's a duplicate.

Comment: I need to remove  "Object { name="version_Value",  value=1}," from the above JSON object

Comment: Again, it's not JSON and there's no such thing as a 'JSON object'. I also already linked to a question which has your answer.